# How to Create Virtual USBs on Ubuntu host connected to machines in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive

Two steps to do:

1. I want to create virtual USB drivers on my Ubuntu host
2. Then, I want to connect every virtual machine in the virualbox to one of
   those virtual USB drivers for copying things between those servers (machines) .

I found second step in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox), but couldn't find first step or anything similar!

Does anybody know how to create virtual USB? Does it need a special software of just can be made via command line?

**Update**

After days of searching I found this [link](http://low-level-world.com/index.html) and seems it has what I've been looking for!
However, I couldn't install it. Can you give me a hand in this?

The readme file says:

> To compile the driver you need to have source codes of your  OS
>   kernel. Default Makefile is searching  for kernel source  codes in
>   "/usr/src/linux" folder to  compile the driver. If  your  kernel  is 
>   in  the  other  folder  you can point its  location in the file system
>   using KERNELDIR variable.
>
> e.g.: make KERNELDIR=/usr/src/kernel-source-2.6.17.5
>
> After successful driver  compilation there will be tusbd.ko  file  in 
>   the "/modules/src/tusbd/"  folder.  This  file is  necessary for USB
>   Server operation

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If this is just for sharing files, wouldn't it be easier to do with a network shared drive?

Comment: no actually it's for testing the application I'm developing in my company  , it must be a USB and only a USB , I'm so tired of searching and asking ! it's like no body ever had done this :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally me and a friend came across a solution for this problem .
we add a virtual hard disk to the machine and yes ! 
it's working now :D

Comment: Can you provide the steps you followed?